# get the height of UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview

I am having trouble in getting UIView's height. I am trying to get the height and (x,y) of my UIView. The view is add as subview of Other view

```
float y = optionalView.frame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"%.1f",y);
```

but it always return 0.0 . need guidance.

Thanks...

Comment: using IB I have added the UIView

Comment: can you post the code where you initialize the UIView, please? If optionalView is a UIView (not a UIViewController, maybe?) and it's a correct visible pointer when you call it... your code should work fine...

Comment: then it may be not linked well with your pointer... can you get other property of optionalView? ...alpha, hidden? the 2 lines of code you send are correct, the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: ok solved.. after restarting th XCode

Comment: lol... let me guess: you linked it in IB, but didn't "save" it...?

Comment: n ya also noticed that if write 
NSLog(@"%d fgd",optionalView.frame.origin.x); it doesn't print the value but if I write 
int x = optionalView.frame.origin.x;
NSLog(@"%d",x);
it prints the value !!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you want to log it

```
NSLog(@"My view's frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(myView.frame));
```

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried this @Maulik?

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);
```

Comment: This does not work for UIView but UIViewController, so this is not answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

However, if the class is UIView itself, then only:

```
CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height
```